Google Apps Script Oauth2 Continuous Access
I am using Oauth2 to connect to the Microsoft Graph API with Google Apps Script. First, I click on the url that comes with the authorize() function and gain access. But after a certain period of time, access expires and I need to gain access with the authorize() function again. How can I ensure that access is always active? I think refresh tokens are used, but I couldn't get the result I wanted.
My code:
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
var REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/PROJECT_ID/usercallback';
var TOKEN_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
var AUTH_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
var SCOPE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('MicrosoftGraph')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(AUTH_URL)
    .setTokenUrl(TOKEN_URL)
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope(SCOPE)
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline') // Yenileme token'ı almak için gerekli
    .setParam('prompt', 'consent');
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization successful. You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization failed.');
  }
}

function authorize() {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and authorize the app: ' + authorizationUrl);
    // E-posta ile gönderme örneği
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Authorize Google Apps Script', 'Open the following URL and authorize the app: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}

function fetchMicrosoftGraphData() {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'; // Örnek Microsoft Graph API çağrısı
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(result);
  } else {
    Logger.log('No access. Re-authorizing...');
    authorize();
  }
}

function reset() {
  getOAuthService().reset();
}

I wanted the tokens to be constantly renewed, but they were not renewed and I had to manually run the authorise() function to gain access, click on the link it gave and gain access. Continuous access should be active without my intervention.
